# When a matrix differential equation is length preserving?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I know a matrix transformation $Q x$ is length-preserving iff $QQ^T=I$.

Now I want to know the condition that a matrix differential equation $\dot x=Ax$ is length preserving.

What I tried was to discretize that equation like

$$
\frac{x^{n+1}-x^n}{\delta t} = Ax
$$
$$
x^{n+1}=x^n+\delta tAx
$$
and conclude $Q=I+\delta tA$. But this is merely correct for Euler-backward discretization. Moreover it suggests that length preserving of matrix differential equation always depends on $\delta t$ (except for $A=0$ of course).

Was the path I took correct? Is there any method to check this independent of discretization?

Comment: The solution is $x(t) = e^{tA} x_0$. So you need $A= e^{tA}$ to have $QQ^T = I$. This is true if and only if $A^T = -A$.

Comment: Even if $A$ is time-dependent? @ArcticChar